# Proceed To Checkout Without Returning Any Payment Gateway Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook, payment-gateway, checkout

I would like to have a custom button underneath the "place order" one, to allow the customer to get one order and to end up in "pending-payment" status without paying now.

I don't want to use a "pay later" payment gateway, because it doesn't need any commitment from the customer to pay, it's to get a proforma invoice.

I want that even if a payment gateway is selected by default when clicking the "ask for a proforma invoice", no payment is returned, and the customer can pay later. (a bit different that to choosing a "cod" or "cheque" payment)

I tried the `add_filter( ‘woocommerce_order_needs_payment’, ‘__return_false’ );` hook within an `add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'create_order');` into a custom submit button, but it doesn't work.

I guess it's possible because I found `WC_Checkout::process_order_without_payment( int $order_id )` on the woocommerce documentation.
Is it possible?

I hope it's understandable

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't post ALLCAPS, it's considered shouting/rude.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I'll not do it again

Comment: Basically you just have to provide a submit button, on the checkout page that can change the status of the order to "pending". The "problem" with this will be that to change the order status, you will need the order id and that order ID is assigned in a later process somewhere between the checkout page and the creation of the order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see, if I can't get the order ID at this stage it's annoying.

Comment: I wanted to end up to the thank you page with no payment returned, as the order has been created but no payment gateway has been selected and it can be choose later. Or maybe hide a cheque or cod gateway that would be only selected with this button...